# WIF ClaimsPrincipal.BootstrapContext is always null ( 4.5)

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, acs

I've got an MVC5 app defended by JWT Tokens from ACS.

Unauthenticated users are redirected to the ACS login page, where they select an IdP and enter their credentials.  They are redirected back to my MVCApp with a JWT Token thats authenticated using the Microsoft JWT Token handler. Beautiful!

I want to re-use my token, passing it my web API, added saveBootstrapContext="true" to the identityConfiguration node in my web.config

However, the ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.BootstrapContext is always null.

How can I capture the bootstrap context to fetch the token?

Answer (score 0):

Killing my chrome session and whacking my cookies seems to have alleviated this issue.  I'm not getting a Bootstrap Context value.